# Indefinite integral involving product of sinc with cosine: $\displaystyle\int\operatorname{sinc}^2(ax) \cos(bx)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, transcendental-functions

I try to solve this indefinite integral:

\begin{equation}
 \int\,\mathrm{sinc}^{2}\left(ax\right)\,\cos\left(bx\right)\,\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

whith $\mathrm{sinc}\left(x\right) = \frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}$. I tried to do integratin by parts using the D-I-method / tabular method. However, this resulted in very lengthy and complicated expressions, independent which part is considered for differentiation and for integration. Do you know some other strategy how to obtain a solution? Of course I checked WolframAlpha and seeing that there exists a solution lets me feel at least certain that an analytic solution exists.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sinc%28a*x%29%5E%282%29+*+cos%28b*x%29+dx

Your help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Being lazy, I threw it against the Alpha wall and got this:
integral(sin^2(a x) cos(b x))/x^2 dx = (x (2 a - b) Si((2 a - b) x) + 2 a x Si((2 a + b) x) + b x Si((2 a + b) x) + cos(x (2 a - b)) + cos(x (2 a + b)) - 2 b x Si(b x) - 2 cos(b x))/(4 x) + constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We first rewrite the integral $$\int \operatorname{sinc}^2 ax \cos bx \,dx$$ (for $a \neq 0$) in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, giving a constant multiple of
$$I_{a, b} := \int \frac{\sin^2 a x \cos b x \,dx}{x^2} .$$
Applying a double-angle identity and then a product-to-sum identity then yields
\begin{multline}I_{a, b} = \int \frac{\frac12 (1 - \cos 2 a x) \cos b x \,dx}{x^2} \\= \frac{1}{2} \left[\int \frac{\cos b x \,dx}{x^2} - \frac12 \int \frac{\cos (2 a + b) x + \cos (2 a - b) x}{x^2} \,dx\right] .\end{multline}
Then, in terms of $$J_k := \int \frac{\cos k x \,dx}{x^2},$$
the integral $I_{a, b}$ is
$$I_{a, b} = \frac12 J_b - \frac14 J_{2 a + b} - \frac14 J_{2 a - b} .$$
Now, to evaluate $J_k$, we integrate by parts with $u = \cos k x$, $v = \frac{dx}{x^2}$, giving
$$J_k = - \frac{\cos k x}{x} - k \int \frac{\sin k x}{x} \,dx = -\frac{\cos k x}{x} - k \operatorname{Si}(k x) + C,$$
where $\operatorname{Si}(u) := \int_0^u \frac{\sin t \,dt}{t}$ is the [sine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) function.

Putting everything together and reorganizing the $\cos$ terms for compactness gives
\begin{multline}
\color{#bf0000}{
\boxed{
\small
\int \operatorname{sinc}^2 ax \cos bx \,dx \\
\small = \frac{1}{4 a^2}\left[(2 a - b) \operatorname{Si} ((2 a - b) x) - 2 b \operatorname{Si} (b x) + (2 a + b) \operatorname{Si} ((2 a + b) x)\right]
\small - \frac{\sin^2 ax \cos b x}{a^2 x} + C}} .
\end{multline}

The case $b = 0$ reduces to
$$\int \operatorname{sinc}^2 u \,du = \operatorname{Si}(2 u) - \frac{\sin^2 u}{u} + C .$$

Comment: thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

How about a reduction formula?
(I took the case $a=b=1$ of the original question.)
Consider integrals of the form
$$
J(a,b,c) = \int\frac{\sin^a(x)\cos^b(x)}{x^c}\;dx ,
$$
where $c$ is a positive integer.  We want a "reduction formula" to evalute this in terms of similar integrals with smaller value of $c$.
Integrate by parts to get something like
$$
J(a,b,c) = -\frac{\sin^a(c)\cos^b(x)}{(c-1)x^{c-1}}
+\frac{1}{c-1}\int\left(\frac{(a+b)\sin^{a-1}(x)\cos^{b+1}(x)}{x^{c-1}}
-\frac{b\sin^{a-1}(x)\cos^{b-1}(x)}{x^{c-1}}\right)\;dx
\\
=-\frac{\sin^a(c)\cos^b(x)}{(c-1)x^{c-1}}
+\frac{a+b}{c-1}J(a-1,b+1,c-1)-\frac{b}{c-1}J(a-1,b-1,c-1) .
$$
Starting values $J(a,b,1)$ involve sine integral $\operatorname{Si}$ and/or cosine integral $\operatorname{Ci}$.

Comment: very interesting recursive approach. thanks for the inspiration!